# Laravel send mail when status change

Tags: laravel

I have created an Event and Listener. When a user's profile is updated it's gonna trigger and send the email.

`boot` method in `User` model:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::updated(function ($user) {
        if ($user->user_status == 'Active') {
            event(new UserStatusChangeEvent($user));
        }
    });
}
```

The `UserStatusChangeEvent` event class looks like this:

```
class UserStatusChangeEvent
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

I am adding the listener in `EventServiceProvider`'s `$listen` variable:

```
UserStatusChangeEvent::class => [
    UserStatusChangeListener::class,
],
```

And in the `listener`, I am sending mail by using the *Mail Facade*.

Now the thing is this is sending emails to all users whose status is `Active` and `updated` their profiles. But I want this to trigger when `user_status` becomes `Active` not on anything else.

Like there are 2 fields in users table **user_status** and **is_active** when the user logged in the is_active will become 1 and when the user logged out the status becomes 0 now if the user logged in or out, the event in boot method will trigger if the status is active but I want this to trigger when only status column changes should not trigger if  **is_active** changes

Comment: instead of boot method u should fire event in the controller update method

Comment: There are so many ways user can update data and then the admin can also update data so I am looking for a way more convenient than firing an event in the controller it should do automatically.

Comment: I am confused, what is the actual problem ? You want to trigger this when `user_status` changes to `Active`, but you also said that it is sending all mails to those users... I don't get what the issue is.

Comment: @matiaslauriti
there are 2 fields in users table **user_status** and **is_active** when the user logged in the is_active will become 1 and when the user logged out the status becomes 0 now if the user logged in or out, the event in boot method will trigger if the status is active but I want this to trigger when only status column changes should not trigger if  **is_active** changes

Comment: @HamzaMughal ooohhh, I understand now, let me answer it.

Comment: @matiaslauriti it will be great help

Comment: @HamzaMughal did my answer work ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti, sorry I wasn't around just tested works like a charm. Thanks A lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you explained, you only want this to trigger when the column `user_status` changes. But when the user logs in or out, you change `is_active`, and because the user already has `user_status = "Active"` it will trigger every time you do any change to the user (except changing `user_status`).

So, to see if `user_status` was updated, you can take advantage of the `dirty` status.

```php
static::updated(function ($user) {
    if ($user->wasChanged('user_status') && $user->user_status === 'Active') {
        event(new UserStatusChangeEvent($user));
    }
});
```

See that I used [`wasChanged`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#examining-attribute-changes).